# Validate vbScript argument names

Tags: vbscript, arguments, wsh

I am calling a vbScript from PowerShell, with arguments that are defined in a text string, and I want to validate that the arguments being used are correct. Say my valid arguments are **ARG1**, **ARG2** & **ARG3**, and someone has a string of `"/ARGG1:one /ARG2:two"`, I want to validate the named arguments against an array of valid arguments and catch that **ARGG1**.
Where I am failing is in getting the names of the named arguments. I can reference a particular named argument with `WScript.Arguments.Named("ARG1")` for example. But I can't seem to loop through WScript.Arguments.Named and return the actual argument names used.
Something like this

```
For Each Argument In WScript.Arguments.Named
    msgBox Argument.name
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

When iterating the `Named` argument collection you are accessing the key *(argument name)* not the `WshNamed` object itself. If you pass the key back into the collection you will be able to access the value for that Named Argument.

```
Dim key
For Each key In WScript.Arguments.Named
    Dim argument: argument = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item(key)
    Call WScript.Echo(key) 'Return argument name
    Call WScript.Echo(argument) 'Return argument value
Next
```

Output:

```
ARG1
one
ARG2
two
```